# Facebook Graph API: Know URLs the user has commented?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm considering implementing Facebook's comments plugin on my site. The problem is that I need to know the pages on my site where a user has commented.

I have read Facebook's documentation but I don't find a proper permission to know this.

Is it possible to know which URLs a user has commented? In such case which permissions does my app need?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know you have already accepted an answer, but i think this will help you.

You can first generate the code for [Facebook Comments here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/comments/).

For each page that you implement the comments plugin in, you'll be providing a `href` of the page the user is reading/visiting, as it is required by the plugin.

You can use the [Javascript SDK](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/) to listen to [Facebook events](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Event.subscribe/), for comments specifically you have the `comment.create` event, which is fired every time a comment is made. This event passes a `response` object to its callback function, which contains the `href` mentioned previously, and the `commentID` of the comment just generated. Hence you can easily track which page(url) a user has commented on.

Example (see how we can listen to the comment.create event):

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
      appId      : 'YOUR_APP_ID', // App ID
      channelUrl : '//WWW.YOUR_DOMAIN.COM/channel.html', // Channel File
      status     : true, // check login status
      cookie     : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
      xfbml      : true  // parse XFBML
    });

    // Additional initialization code here, this is where we listen to events
    FB.Event.subscribe('comment.create',
      function(response) {
        alert('You commented on the URL: ' + response.href + 'CommentID: ' + response.commentID);
        // do an ajax call to server to store user,commentID,href info if you require
      }
    );
  };

  // Load the SDK Asynchronously
  (function(d){
     var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
     if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
     js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
     js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
     ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
   }(document));
</script>
```

Comment: It helps a lot. With this I could theoretically use AJAX in place of the alert to insert the HREF and the CommentID into my database every time a comment is made. Right? Just I won't be able to know the comment's text.

Comment: i have already mentioned in the code that you can do ajax call, so that should be clear. you can also get the comment's text by calling the graph api with the commentID, simply call : `https://graph.facebook.com/commentID`

Comment: Is there a way to echo the comment's ID together with the comment's box ID?

Comment: i'm not aware of any comment box id, where did you see that?

Comment: In the alert box, where it says commentID: that ID is actually the comment's box ID. I get the same for all comments on the box. You can see it here: http://lujanventas.com/test.php

Comment: no alert showing for me, you can't be getting the same commentID, each comment is different, so they have to be different id.

Comment: ok in my test page i'm getting different ids, but not the complete id, this could be a bug, because till yesterday it was working fine

Comment: @Liso22 i recently came across [this bug](http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/457493477614026?browse=search_50117b894df0d6925218896), which precisely says that the commentId is not being returned correctly, even though the documentation says so.

Answer (score 1):

Call

```
graph.facebook.com/USER_ID/feed&fields=link
```

for each user you want to query about. This call returns id, name and the link field which is a url to the object commented on.  Not all posts will have a link field so you need to check for null. You can then compare the link field to find matches with your urls.

The feed includes comment posts from the Comment Box Plugin only in the case of a user leaving the “Post to Facebook” box checked when she posts a comment.

You need to ask users for read_stream permission.

This all assumes you know know who the user is. You need to keep track of those users on your side since there is no way to query FB's API for "users who have commented on my site".

Comment: Thanks, can I ask you something else? Is it possible knowing an object's IDs to get user ids from those who commented including those who haven't checked "post to facebook" box?

Comment: I don't think it's possible but it's risky to confirm something as impossible:). I haven't seen it documented in the API.